# how to give access to a user who rejoins? sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, access-denied

There's a user who rejoined the project. So, his login was created again in the active directory.

In spite, of giving access this user is not able to access the SharePoint sites. Also, I wasn't able to find this user's name in the **MembershipGroupId=0** link (aka the **user information list**).

We are using **SharePoint 2010** on **Windows Server 2008 R2.**

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

If the user was created again -and not just ENABLED again- in Active Directory, maybe it's initial username was changed (i.e. from john.doe to john.doe2), then you need to add the user again in the `/_layouts/user.aspx` page.

Comment: The user is added to the /_layout/user.aspx page (If i'm not wrong it is the site permission spage?) but unable to access any site.

Comment: can you add an image of the output of the "check permissions" dialog?

Comment: The user has to appear in the dialog like this: https://i.imgsafe.org/163b90550c.png

Comment: I'm unable to open the image link given by you. I will check and get back later on this. Please keep checking this thread. I'm in real need of some help on this. Thank you. :)

Comment: Hi @Marcelo Espinosa, i viewed the image shared by you. The said user also appears the same way. I can see the user listed in /_layouts/user.aspx page after giving appropriate permission but still user gets access denied.

Comment: Is the user trying to access the default landing page (i.e. root of the web app)? If it's another page you can check the permissions for that page, maybe it's not allowing the user into that place. You cantry to access another site area too, one that you are 100% sure that the user has permissions to view. Are you trying to add the user directly to the site or inside a SharePoint Group?

Comment: We have two web apps. http://servername:port1 and http://servername:port2. User can access http://servername:port1 but cannot access http://servername:port2. I have added this user directly to the site and not any group.

Comment: check in both sites the /_catalogs/users/detail.aspx to find if the information stored in the list is the same for the user, if not goto your central admin -> monitoring -> timer jobs and find and re-run the User Profile Service Aplication Proxy timer jobs for the web app who doesn't accepts the user (maybe the User Profile Service is not connected to your web app 2) and you can try to change the user's password too to see if the synchronization is triggered.